# How to scroll page with recyclerview and other items on page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In xml layout i have one recycler view. cardview on top of recyclerview. so how to scroll both items at same time.

Comment: Why don't you add your CardView as a ViewHolder into your RecyclerView ?

Answer (score 0):

use this recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your cardview, recyclerview and other views in NestedScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Great, please consider it accept and upvote so it may help others as well  :)

Answer (score 0):

Add card view and recycler view inside the **NestedScrollView** and set **nestedScrollingEnabled=false** if you want to scroll as parent.So,your xml looks like as per below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: @NinadHiray Ok Thanks.If it is work for you so can you give this answer as marked?So,it's helpful for other people.